# In a 4n*4n matrix find a n*n sub matrix Which have the maxium sum for every element. which runs in time O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Have no idea how to make the time complexity O(n^2). The  brute force time complexity is like O(n^4)

Comment: What is _maximum sum for every element_ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks like homework I will just give a hint.

Lets call the original matrix A, build a matrix S where the element Sij is the sum of all Amn with 1 <= m <= i and 1 <= n <= j. The effort to build S is O(n^2). With the help of this matrix S you can determine the sum of a rectangular sub-matrix of A in O(1).